# how to show error messages in asp.net MVC2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

while coding in asp.net C# MVC 2.0, how to show error messages let say there is try {}..Catch{} or If Else ... then if i want to show  error messages , then how can i code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return an error in your `ViewData`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    try
    {
        // Do something that causes an error
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       ViewData["Error"] = ex.Message;
    }
    return View();
}
```

And get it within your page by using `ViewData["Error"]`.